# Webpack module Federation multiple entry points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am creating a micro-frontend application with webpack ModuleFederation plugin. What I want to achieve is I want to bundle some local libraries in the remoteEntry.js file. Is there any configuration which I can do which can help me with that.

```
const devConfig = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: ['index.js', 'node_modules/some_library.js'],
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8081/",
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: "/index.html",
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "marketing",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./MarketingApp": "./src/bootstrap",
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

In the above example, I am using 2 entry points in my application one is index.js and other is some_library.js which gets bundled properly on the local environment. But during module federation, it is not bundled in remoteEntry.js. Hence I cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to include the local library `some_library.js` in the `remoteEntry.js` file, you need to modify your `shared` property in the `ModuleFederationPlugin` configuration to use *[Object syntax](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/#object-syntax)*. Since it(`some_library.js`) is not a part of the `packageJson.dependencies`, you need to add it explicitly.

```js
// ...rest of your settings
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "marketing",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./MarketingApp": "./src/bootstrap",
      },
      shared: {
        ...packageJson.dependencies,
        "some_library": {
          import: "node_modules/some_library.js",
          // Adjust the version if need be
          version: "x.x.x",
          // optional, in case you want to ensure only one instance of library to be used.
          singleton: true,
        }
      },
    }),
// ...rest
```

---

##### Resources and References:

1. [Singleton hint](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/#singleton)
2. [version hint](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/#version)
3. [import hint](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/#import)